# "&" or "&amp;" in Google AdWords conversion tracking code?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm installing Google AdWords conversion tracking code on my site, and noticed that part of the code that Google provides uses `&amp;` in a URL query string. E.g.

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1000252671/
?value=0&amp;label=EQfkDGsBrkTPj_YU6FH&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
```

However, [a Google AdWords support page shows `&` being used instead of `&amp;`](http://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054?hl=en&from=86276&rd=1) (expand "Track conversions on your website", then expand "Step 2", then see the last few lines of the 2nd code block)

```
<img height=1 width=1 border=0 src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/
conversion/1234567890/?value=10.0&label=Purchase&script=0">
```

Should I be using `&amp;` or `&` ?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers will probably let you get away with just `&`, but according to the HTML specification, you have to use the *character entity reference* `&amp;`.

You can check for yourself using the W3's validator (http://validator.w3.org); when not using  `&amp;` it will complain **"cannot generate system identifier for general entity "label""**.